# How to make updates to windows 8 file remotely

Tags: windows, permissions

We have a simple problem, we are setting up our new server and before we point our DNS to the server we want to check everything so we are changing the hosts file on our Windows 8 machine to do this.

That all works fine the problem is we are migrating tons of sites over and we have employees that are testing the sites for us and they are not very tech savvy, and because we are updating the hosts file alot during the day we figured we could temporarily share the /etc/ folder that contains the hosts file.

However we can only view it from another network PC and not update it with the new sites.

It gives an "accessed denied" error

We have tried everything changed ownership granted administrator permission, granted permissions to Everyone. Still we can't update it. And having my IT team go to the PC individually and update them is taking to long.

Any Suggestions?

And yes we know this is bad security protocol, but again it is Temporary so no lecture comments on that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a very simple problem, we never set the share permission just the file permissions.